# Set-ACL on AD Computer Object

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I am attempting to `Set-Acl` on a Computer Object in AD. Firstly I get the ACL using:

```
$acl = (Get-Acl AD:\'CN=Tester1,OU=Ou1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,DC=Contoso,DC=com').Access
```

Which gives me all the ACL for that computer object. I then use:

```
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Computername","FullControl")))
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful. My aim is to add a computer object to the computer object 'Tester1' and give it Full Access permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActiveDirectory isn't a filesystem. You must create a new ACE for an AD object as an [`ActiveDirectoryAccessRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
$path = "AD:\CN=Tester1,OU=Ou1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,DC=Contoso,DC=com"
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule('DOMAIN\Computername','FullControl')
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

Answer (score 1):

ACE for AD objects you must create with [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx) object instead of System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule.

Good description and example is here: [Add Object Specific ACEs using Active Directory Powershell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/10/13/add-object-specific-aces-using-active-directory-powershell/)