# Read/Write Public Information AD with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm currently working on a script for installation. Part of this process involves creating the service account users in AD and I would like to set the security to allow Read/Write Public Information AD. I would like to use powershell cmdlet instead of GUI. I can't figure out how can i archive to it.  Is it any security impact if i gave a/c to Read/Write Public Information AD?

Here is sample screenshot of account on AD (Group Managed Service Account).
[image]

Here is sample screenshot of account on AD (Normal User as Service Account).
[image]

Comment: Is that a service account? Doesn't look like a service account. Although it resembles the properties of an OU, I do not think Managed Service Account allows child OUs.

Comment: Hi, i have two account. One is under Managed Service Account and another is Normal user account for services account. I created the new OU and normal a/c is under new OU. I would like to apply same method (Read/Write Public Information) to Group Managed Service account and normal services account using with powershell cmdlet. I added another screenshot to clear.

Comment: Do not tamper with AD permissions unless you have a very good reason to do so. If you mess up you may end up having to restore your AD from backup, which is something most people I know of try to avoid like the plague. Please explain what actual problem you're trying to solve in the first place. AD accounts should already be able to read public information by default and I would not recommend giving *carte blanche* for writing all public data..

Comment: I agree with Ansgar, even if you had a very good reason for providing the access you require on the account, it is possible to do so to individual properties on the account as opposed to just allowing R/W to all public properties. You need to explain what exactly the process requires (does it just need to write a value to a property against its AD account?) - once you've properly described what you require, then we can assist.

Comment: Thanks AdamParsons and AnsgarWiechers. Actually, i'm following the one of MS installation guide. The documentation describe as per below 5.Choose SELF in the Group or user names list. 
6. Under Permissions for SELF, in the lower part of the panel, scroll down to Write public information and select the Allow column. 
7.Choose OK to exit the Properties panel, and close Active Directory Users and Computers. I afraid to give service a/c to read/write on pub. information, that why i asking. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/provisioning-the-microsoft-dynamics-nav-server-account#DUA

Comment: The guide tells you to change permissions on the Users container, not the entire domain, AFAICS.

Comment: For changing permissions on AD objects [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31377331/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for sharing the links. I not try to change entire AD. I just want to change on the user account only. Any security impact if I give read/write permission on user account?