# Any Way To Open a Users Properties in Active Directory Users and Computers from Powershell Command Line?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Would like to be able to open a newly created users properties sheet from powershell so that permissions can be added by the GUI.

Comment: I am confused at this point about what is required. `Get-ADUser newuser -properties *` will return most properties of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Don't count on it. There's no built-in way to do it.

The only way to open the AD property sheets is with the Windows API (C++). It *could* be possible if you could make a DLL in C++ that made it available to use in other code, but it's not easy.

There is a description of it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/active-directory-users-and-computers-property-sheets), but I use the word "description" loosely since it really isn't clear. There's even an example of it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/adsi/activedir/propsheethost), but when I tried it, it only showed the Security and COM+ tabs (which, I guess could work for you).

But that would still be a lot of work to get it to work from PowerShell.

But you can use `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` as the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31377331/1202807) shows:

```
$path = "AD:\CN=Tester1,OU=Ou1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,DC=Contoso,DC=com"
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule('DOMAIN\Computername','FullControl')
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

Not as intuitive as the UI, I know.